# Can't fix Else Without If error

Tags: vba, excel

I have been writing a code that will export some data from excel row by row to word. It seems to work except that it gives me an "Else without If" error. I cannot for the life of me find out why it's still doing that even though I took the necessary precautions (I think).

```
Sub test()
    Dim objword As Object
    Dim fNameAndPath As Variant
    Dim fNameAndPath2 As Variant

    fNameAndPath = "C:\test"
    fNameAndPath2 = "C:\test"

    i = 2
    While Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 3))
        If Cells(i, 9) = "End of Probation Per" Then _
        Set objword = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        objword.Visible = True
        objword.Documents.Open (fNameAndPath)
        objword.Activate

        With objword.ActiveDocument
            .Bookmarks("EmpName").Range.Text = Cells(i, 2).Value
            .Bookmarks("EndDate").Range.Text = Cells(i, 11).Value

        filename = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("MyFileName.xls", _
        "Excel files,*.xlsx", 1, "Select your folder and filename")

        If TypeName(filename) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename
            ActiveWorkbook.Close False
        Else: Cells(i, 9).Font.Italic = True
        End If
    i = i + 1
Wend

End Sub
```

Suggestions to fix this elementary coding error are welcome!

Comment: You have 2 `If` and only 1 `End If`.

Comment: You have an unclosed `With`  block. You have an Else without an If. It doesn't get much more straighforward than that.  Your second `If` statement terminates on the same line and **cannot** have an Else clause, so the Else that you do have is orphaned.

Comment: @DavidZemens I think that last `Else` is for the very first `If` because the second `If` is a single line statement. It's over right away.

Comment: Yes, @Brad I see that :) The missing `End With` complicates it -- really it could go either way, but I think your answer is correct.

Comment: i just edited your code for as far as i was able to, and there is a lot wrong with it. after the first if for example is a _ as if you want that line to be longer. But it doesn't look like you want. And as another example you have a ':' after your else. I really cant follow this code

Comment: two if and only one end if ; same goes for two with and only one end with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no `End With`. Let's edit this with some formatting to expose the errors

```
Sub test 
Dim objword As Object
Dim fNameAndPath As Variant
Dim fNameAndPath2 As Variant

fNameAndPath = "C:\test"
fNameAndPath2 = "C:\test"

i = 2
While Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 3))
    If Cells(i, 9) = "End of Probation Per" Then 
        Set objword = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        objword.Visible = True
        objword.Documents.Open (fNameAndPath)
        objword.Activate
        With objword.ActiveDocument
              .Bookmarks("EmpName").Range.Text = Cells(i, 2).Value
              .Bookmarks("EndDate").Range.Text = Cells(i, 11).Value
          filename = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("MyFileName.xls", _
            "Excel files,*.xlsx", 1, "Select your folder and filename")
        End With '### THIS WAS MISSING
        If TypeName(filename) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub 'single line If so no end if necessary

        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename
        ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Else
        Cells(i, 9).Font.Italic = True
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately even after adding the End With it still gives me the same error. The code now looks exactly like the code you put above.

Comment: You need to remove the line continuation at the end of `If Cells(i, 9) = "End of Probation Per" Then _`

Comment: @Rory I didn't even see that. sneaky. I think you are correct.

Comment: @Brad Credit has to go to SmartIndenter - the inset `Set objword...` line gave it away. :)

Comment: @Casz146 please consider marking Brad's answer as "Accepted" if it has solved your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Add a line break after "then" and change the code below because it won't execute after the exit sub

```
If TypeName(filename) = "Boolean" Then 
Exit Sub
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename
ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Else: Cells(i, 9).Font.Italic = True
End If
```

Comment: Yes it will execute *after* that statement.  If that statement returns `False`, the `Exit Sub` is *not* executed.